# How to set a tap event on syncfusion listview item?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, data-binding, syncfusion

I'm trying to trigger an event when the user clicks/taps on a list item to open some more details from the item, but I cannot get to catch the tap on the item, this is my listView:

```
            <syncfusion:SfListView x:Name="bandListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={local2:BandInfoRepository}, Path=BandInfo, Mode=TwoWay}"
                ItemSize="100"
                ItemTapped="OnBandClick"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" 
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" >
                <syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid RowSpacing="0" Padding="0,12,8,0" ColumnSpacing="0" Margin="5">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid RowSpacing="5" Padding="8,10,8,10" BackgroundColor="#dbe8ff">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0.9*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Path=BandImage}"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    HeightRequest="80"
                                    WidthRequest="70"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                                />
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" 
                                    Padding="5,-5,0,0"
                                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="1">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Path=BandName}"
                                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                                        FontSize="16"
                                        TextColor="#000000" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Path=BandDescription}"
                                        Opacity="0.54"
                                        TextColor="#000000"
                                        FontSize="13" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                            <BoxView Grid.Row="1" 
                                HeightRequest="1"
                                Opacity="0.75"
                                BackgroundColor="#CECECE" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
            </syncfusion:SfListView>
```

This is the event I'm trying to trigger(Just trying to catch the tap):

```
public void OnBandClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("hello");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
void OnBandClick(object sender, Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    if (bandListView.SelectedItem != null)
    {
         // Do Something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reported issue “SfListView ItemTapped event does not trigger” occurs due to SfListViewRenderer might not be initialized in your native projects. So, we recommend to refer the following UG documentation link to initialize the SfListView renderer to resolve the issue at the sample level.

Launching SfListView in each platform: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/getting-started#launching-the-sflistview-on-each-platform

Comment: I burnt way too much time on this due to missing it in the documentation. The list will show your items but different functionality will not occur (e.g. tapcommands) without being initialised.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `SelectionChanged` event.  The Syncfusion [docs](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/selection) have an entire section about the different selection modes supported by the control and how to use them.

Comment: Already tried with SelectionChanged and SelectionChanging but couldn't get them to work. I followed the documentation from: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/selection step by step.

Comment: Another thing is the items were not being selected.

Comment: do you have SelectionMode set?

Comment: Yes, I have it set up as Single

Comment: have you tried their sample projects?  Otherwise I would probably go their support system for more help

Comment: Yeah, I downloaded a couple of them and even copied and pasted the code and didn't get it to work. I will go get support from them. Thanks for your help.